# Is there a way to detect if a map is being played in multiplayer? (1.15)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm attempting to make a fully customized map that I want to only be single player. I'm going to be using custom sounds with my voice, and wanted to determine whether or not a group of people are playing multiplayer so I can present them with a custom clip of me saying "this map will only work in Single Player" or something similar.

I've thought about making a simple command block that triggers after *x* amount of time using chain command blocks, with the following command;

```
execute unless @a[limit=1] run playsound ..
```

The problem with this, however, is I'm not entirely certain that the `limit` selector will work this way. In theory, of course, it should, but being unable to test multiplayer myself makes this a little difficult.

Another, more sure-fire, way would be to do three scoreboards and match them all up together to create a tally system, but not only would that be countless hours of tedious brain-knocking before eventually making a flawless system, but it *wouldn't* be necessarily flawless and could mess up at any given moment.

Would there be any way to find how many players there are in a world--and if so, to run a command if there are *x* people?

Comment: If you need a test server for multiplayer stuff, just send me a mail and I can quickly set one up and put an AFK player into it. And no, that selector does not work that way. `@a[limit=1]` is the same as `@r` (except that it doesn't randomise every time) and that succeeds `/execute unless`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a scoreboard objective:

```
/scoreboard objectives add players dummy
```

and run this in a repeating command block:

```
/execute store result score map players run execute if entity @e[type=player]
```

to run your command:

```
execute if score map players matches 2.. run <command>
```

^ this only runs if there are 2 or more players in the world.

Comment: I'm a little confused on where ``map`` comes in there. I'm fairly certain it's supposed to be a player, but I'm not quite sure what it means here.

Comment: You are correct to think that it should be a player. However, it doesn't have to be a real player. You can type in any name you want, and the game will create what's knows as a "fake player". The only difference between a real player and a fake player is that the fake player doesn't physically exist in the world, making it easier to store data.

Comment: I actually didn't know about that, that is incredibly useful to me now lmao

Answer (score 0):

Rather than attempt to scoreboard, you could use a spawn detector.

Basically, when a new player logs in, they spawn in the spawn region. Then, when they spawn in - Increment a counter or mechanism somewhere. When a second player logs in, that happens again and you can use that to detect more than one players have joined.

Don't forget to `/setspawn` after the player joins otherwise deaths may count as another login.

---

A way to do this is to have the entire spawn chunk covered in tripwire connected to tripwire hooks. Then, feed the tripwire into your counting mechanism.

Comment: That won't work for my map, sadly.